# Hertz used in AVR

Tags: timer, avr

I'm very new to AVR and got confused about a question from one of our tutorials. It says:

*"To toggle an output compare pin 8 times per second (4Hz period), what clock prescale and output output compare values do we need?"*

My confusion is:
why it says "4Hz period"? isn't Hertz a measurement for frequency? why is it describing time period?

Comment: you can calculated the time period from Hertz to second(period) in your case 0.25 s(p)(period)  = 4 Hertz which is 8 times per second

Answer (score 0):

You are correct Hz is the unit for frequency. Frequency is changes per second so if you toggle a pin 4 times per second its frequency is 4Hz. The author was problably lazy and did not want to calculate the period time to 1/4 s

Answer (score 0):

Hertz represents >> cycles per seconds in Metrical System SI system.
As mentioned above it tells you how many times a process, event anything else takes place. Mostly everything is measured in Hz because its convenient and has direct relation to time. So one can easily jump back and forth in units.

For the AVR has a system clock which is then prescaled to lower rates for use in different system peripherals. The event loop speed is also measured in Hertz. Currently on mine the loop execution time is 2.7 MHz so very fast loop.